# Issue with Safari and CSS Columns

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am in the process of creating a grid of items using pure CSS and HTML. I have encountered an issue while testing in Safari. I have extracted the code into a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEvyvK?editors=1100) which works in the same way as my grid.

This is the code that I am using to reproduce the issue:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: WhiteSmoke;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  font: 400 14px/1.3 "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;

  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    column-count: 2;
    font-size: 17px;
    column-gap: 20px;
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

.wrapper > * {
  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
  }
}

.wrapper > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">B</div>
  <div class="card">C</div>
  <div class="card">D</div>
  <div class="card">E</div>
</div>
```

Below are two screenshots (both taken on macOS 10.13) showing the different results in Chrome and Safari.

The issue being is that Safari seems to carry over the margin from the previous item in to the second column. Is there a way to force behaviour similar to that of Chrome?

[image: output in Safari and Chrome]

Edit:

I should also include that I have tried setting `.card` to `display: inline-block;` which makes it look fine in both Chrome and Safari, as long as the items are of the same sizes.

Below is another screenshot comparing Chrome and Safari this time with `.card` having `display: inline-block;` and the first item being much larger then the rest.

[image: output in Safari and Chrome with a larger first item and display: inline-block property on .card]

Comment: It seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148078/why-does-safari-render-css-multi-column-layout-differently

Comment: @Andy It looks like Safari has its own way with columns, none of the solutions seem to apply unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, what I don't understand is why if you remove the margin-bottom in your codepen it works

Comment: The margin is being carried, the only work-around for this that I can think of would be to wrap each item in a div to which a padding would be applied instead of the margin.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid add html element,  You can also add **:after** with **display:block** after your div attribute.

```
figure {
     &:after {
            content: "";
            height: 80px;
            display: block;
            @media @mobile {
              height: 40px;
            }
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My team had the same problem and we fixed it by adding extra div at the bottom of the column, with the height of the wanted margin-bottom and width 100%

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? Did you add the div to the end of the element, or the column itself? I'm not sure how you'd accomplish the former.

Also, do you have "break-inside: auto;" or do you want breaks only in between elements?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was removing the margin from the .card element, as @J.Pinkman suggested. Here is an example on how to do it:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-wrapper">
      <div class="card"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<style>
.wrapper {
    columns: 3 auto;
    //your wrapper styles
}
.wrapper .card-wrapper {
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.wrapper .card-wrapper .card {
    //your card styles
}
</style>
```